# how to #define macro only to specific files?

Tags: c++

I have a special macro defined in macro.h, but I want it to be valid only in part of my source files (h/cpp),
how can I do that?

I am afraid that some "bad" user included the macro.h before the source files that must not be familiar with the macro.

how can I prevent it?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you want to *accomplish* with that macro and we can tell you some workaround or a different technique to get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to have macros that are defined only in a files scope by using `#undef`. E.g. :

```
#define MACRO 1

int a = MACRO;

#undef MACRO

int b = MACRO; // ERROR
```

However, this does not work across files unless you rely on the order of includes, which would be bad.

If you want to use macros defined in a `macro.h` in sources, you could have a second `unmacro.h` and include that at the end of the source:

```
 // foo.cpp
 // other includes
 #include "macro.h"
 // no other includes!

 // contents of the source

 #include "unmacro.h"
```

However, I would not recommended it because it is error-prone. Better reconsider if you need to use macros at all. In modern C++ their valid uses are extremely rare.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If it's in `macro.h`, and that file is public, there's no going around it.

A common technique is defining the macro conditionally:

```
#ifdef SOME_CONDITION
#define MY_MACRO
#endif
```

but a "bad" user can just as well define `SOME_CONDITION`.

What you should do is separate public headers from private ones. As you stated the problem, the macro you want hidden probably shouldn't be in a public header at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the area of effect of the macro, especially if you have it in a .h which is included everywhere.

If you want it to exist only in a few .h and .cpp files then one option is to (re)define it at the top of those cpp files. You could also seperate just these macros into its own `.h` and include  it only in the cpp files that need it and not expose it to users of your code.

You might want to give a more specific example if you want more specific answers